# Xamarin Android & iOS - How many Garbage Collectors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, garbage-collection, mono

I understand that Xamarin.Android is split up into Mono and the Android Runtime (ART). Those two entities are communicating via JNI, and the objects within the ART are subject to be collected by the Android provided garbage collector.

[image: Xamarin.Android Architecture - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/Images/architecture1.png]

What I am wondering:
Is there a second Garbage collector in place to collect entirely managed instances (so those solely living in the Mono space), or are those collected by the one living in the ART space?

I am also a bit confused how the situation is for Xamarin.IOS. Ok, there is no garbage collection for Objective-C. But is then the Mono GC the only one in place, and collecting all the instances (both residing in the Mono and the Xamarin.IOS framework)?

Comment: check this article https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/

Comment: Thanks for the link @ShiwankaChathuranga! I am currently trying to get the whole picture of Xamarin Android & iOS in terms of Garbage Collection. When I think that I got a decent knowledge on this topic, I will post an answer to this question.